# “org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally” issue on jenkins(openshift) chrome node

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, chromedriver, maven

I've been trying to run selenium codes over Jenkins (server/openshift). There is chrome node in the jenkins machine for Test Automation - Selenium. I'm getting this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Test ll work on chrome node jenkins-openshift. So I don't need to set browser type as headless, besides If I set browser type as headless, It can't find any UI component of our application. By the way, I developed this code by using cucumber/gherkin.

It works on local via maven clean-verify.

This is our jenkins file to run automated UI test on jenkins:

```
    stage('scm checkout') {
        echo '****************************************\r*** scm checkout'
        checkout scm
        echo '*** show content ***'
        sh "ls -lA"
    }

    stage('build artifact') {
        echo '****************************************\r*** Build Artifact'
        sh "mvn -V -B clean package"
    }

    stage('selenium GUI test') {
            echo '****************************************\r*** Selenium GUI Test'
            sh "mvn -V -B clean verify"
        }
}
```

This is related part of pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                            <includes>
                                <includesFile>**/*UITestsRunner.java</includesFile>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>testing</projectName> 

                            <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                            <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Additionally, this is webdriver settings part of the code :

```
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); //Bypass OS security model
            options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
            options.addArguments("--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests");
            //options.addArguments("--disable-renderer-backgrounding");
            options.addArguments("--disable-infobars"); //Disabling infobars
            //options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); //Open Browser in maximized mode
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); //Overcome limited resource problem
            options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
            options.addArguments("--log-level=3"); // set log level
            options.addArguments("--silent");
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
            webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

There is no issue on local, but on the server, I've been getting this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
>           (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
>           (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
>           (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>         Command duration or timeout: 287 milliseconds
>         Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time: '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z'
>         System info: host: 'jenkins-agent-blue-1', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_192'
>         Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$24(ProtocolHandshake.java:359)
>           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>           at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>           at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:362)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:254)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:178)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:167)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:156)

Comment: Always good to check the chrome version as well as the chromedriver version on your build server in these cases. If it's the same version as your local, you can rule that out. In this case, I'm especially suspicious of the version of chrome on `server/openshift`

Answer (score 1):

First i am not sure you need all these options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); //Bypass OS security model
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
options.addArguments("--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests");
options.addArguments("--disable-renderer-backgrounding");
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars"); 
options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("--log-level=3"); // set log level
options.addArguments("--silent");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Just run your with following 04 options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); //Bypass OS security model   
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments("--headless");
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Apart from these, please check you are using compatible version of chromedriver from chrome browser in your automation testing services.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to add this: 
`options.addArguments("--headless");` because of working on chrome node.
I'll check version compatibility.

Comment: I've just checked the version of chromedriver. I use chrome 73 and chrome driver 73.0.3683.68 on local as same on chrome node jenkins. Tests work fine in local, however I'm still getting the same error. @Vishal

Comment: try adding one more argument "--privileged"

Comment: I've just tried "--privileged" argument. However the result is same.

Comment: did your jenkins is on Docker ?